# Javascript String Replace

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have a string that I would like to replace certain values with empty string. My string is:

```
"col1=,,,&col2=,&col3=,,&item5,item8,"
```

I am trying to replace ",,," with ""

I have tried the following and had no joy, does anyone have any ideas what the best way to achieve this is?

```
var string = "col1=,,,&col2=,&col3=,,&item5,item8,";
var NewCookie = "";

NewCookie = string.replace(",,", ",");
NewCookie = NewCookie.replace(',,,', ',');
NewCookie = NewCookie.replace(',,&', ',');

alert(NewCookie);
```

Thanks

Comment: `&item5,item8` isn't a valid query string. Can you clarify what format you want?

Comment: You can show result what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function:

```
function RemoveConsecutiveCharacter(str, character){
    var newStr = "";

    $.each(str, function(index){
        if(str[index] != character || str[index-1] != character){
            newStr += str[index];
        }
    });

    return newStr;
}
```

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/expertCode/6naAB/

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var result = "col1=,,,&col2=,&col3=,,&item5,item8,".replace(/,+&?/g,',');
```

Result string is: `"col1=,col2=,col3=,item5,item8,"`

or

```
var result = "col1=,,,&col2=,&col3=,,&item5,item8,".replace(/=?,+&?/g,'=&');
```

Result string is: `"col1=&col2=&col3=&item5=&item8=&"`

or

```
var result = "col1=,,,&col2=,&col3=,,&item5,item8,".replace(/,+/g,',');
```

Result string is: `"col1=,&col2=,&col3=,&item5,item8,"`

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
alert( ("col1=,,,&col2=,&col3=,,&item5,item8,").replace(',,,',',') );
```

edit: ah you set NewCookie to "" then you want to replace something in NewCookie  (which is "") in example 2 and 3.
you have to set `var NewCookie = string;` in your example.
or do

```
var NewCookie = string.replace(',,,',',');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing `",,"` to `","` which results in:

```
"col1=,,&col2=,&col3=,&item5,item8,"
```

Therefore, when you do:

```
NewCookie = NewCookie.replace(',,,', ',');
```

there are no longer any `",,,"`

Try rearranging your replace functions:

```
NewCookie = string.replace(',,,', ',');
NewCookie = NewCookie.replace(",,", ",");
NewCookie = NewCookie.replace(',&', ',');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
while(str.indexOf(",,")!=-1){
     str = str.replace(",,",",");
}
```